# Is Python 3.9 supported in Azure Function App yet?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-function-app, python-3.9

As title, does anyone know if Python 3.9 is supported in Azure Function App?

As for now, when I try to debug my function-app using Python 3.9 locally, I got this error:

[image: error message]

Comment: Instead of adding the screenshot of error, please copy paste the text in error and add them in the code format.

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest (8 Dec. 2020) Azure CLI [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli?tabs=azure-cli#app-service), `--runtime python` and `--runtime-version 3.9` options are available as Azure Functions v3 parameter.